# Assigning a value to an object of type AnyObject

Tags: swift, syntax, parse-platform

I have a variable

```
var post :AnyObject?
```

which is an object that I got back from a Parse API call. I want to do this

```
post["caption"]  = captionTextView.text
```

but I get the following error message

**Cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject?' with an index of type 'String'**

I already figured out how to get the value from the post variable. For example, this works just fine to extract the value from the key "caption"

```
captionTextView.text = post!["caption"] as! String!
```

but I don't know how to change the value. I want to change the value of the post variable and then save it so I can updated the Parse database. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you don't want to use a PFObject class instead of an AnyObject?

```
var post :PFObject?
post?["caption"]  = captionTextView.text
```

https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/swift/existing

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I could cast the AnyObject into a PFObject